# What is the maximum number of Azure Active Directory tenants?

Tags: azure

Does anybody know what is the maximum number of Windows Azure Active Directory tenants that can be created per subscription?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one tenant created per subscription. A tenant is an organisation, not a user. See the [What is an Azure AD Tenant?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573650.aspx) MSDN article.

If you are using the free tier, you can create a maximum of 500,000 objects in Windows Azure AD. The default is 150,000; but you can have this limit increased. There is a limit of 10 apps per user.

If you are using the premium service, there is no limit.

See more limitations at the [pricing page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/).

Comment: Actually, that's not true, I can create multiple Windows Azure AD Tenants inside my subscription for the purpose of labs and by the fact that till now there is no option to delete a tenant, I'm afraid I will be hitting the limit. and as quoted from your 1st URL "You will get an Azure AD directory when you sign up for a Microsoft cloud service. You can create additional directories as needed. For example, you might maintain your first directory as a production directory and then create another directory for testing or staging."

Comment: A directory is not a tenant.

Comment: Hello,In the cloud-enabled workplace, a tenant can be defined as a client or organization that owns and manages a specific instance of that cloud service. With the identity platform provided by Microsoft Azure, a tenant is simply a dedicated instance of Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) that your organization receives and owns when it signs up for a Microsoft cloud service such as Azure or Office 365.

Comment: I have quoted the above form your first URL, although that's not the subject of my question. and If you see that an Azure AD Directory is not an AD Tenant then would you please explain the difference ?